# Add file/folder hierarchy to repository and creating a working copy at the same time/place with SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, import, repository, revision-history

I currently have a huge folder/file hierarchy that I have to import in an SVN repository. I know that I could import (using the import command) that hierarchy to SVN and then do a checkout of it at the same place where those files already existed, but this would be very time consuming as the repository is very big.

Is there a way to import the files and make the files/folder already present my working copy (as to avoid doing the checkout after)?

For info, I am using tortoiseSVN on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to import the files and make the files/folder already present my working copy

No